# Realm verify_thread crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

We are experiencing the following crash

```
realm::Realm::verify_thread() const (shared_realm.cpp:274)
```

It happens sporadic but from different flows in our code. 
One of the stacktraces we find is

```
0x00000001003af7ec realm::Realm::verify_thread() const (shared_realm.cpp:274)
0x0000000100339d78 RLMGetObjects (RLMObjectStore.mm:83)
0x0000000100330130 +[RLMObject objectsWithPredicate:] (RLMObject.mm:150)
0x00000001000fa468 -[PrinterRepository getDefaultPrinter] (PrinterRepository.m:35)
0x00000001001faf3c -[PrintService handlePrintJobs] (PrintService.m:106)
```

Our code in [PrinterRepository getDefaultPrinter] is

```
return [[Printer objectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isDefault == 1"]] firstObject];
```

Locally we aren't able to reproduce this yet, we've only seen this happen from time to time with our beta testers.

Our realm version is 0.102.1

Our iOS versions are 9.2.1, 9.3.2 & 9.3.3

Does someone has an idea of the cause of this crash?

Answer (score 1):

Managed Realm objects are thread confined. You're not allowed to pass them around arbitrarily between threads. When you retrieve an object on the main thread, you're only allowed to use it there. When you want to pass it to a background thread, you will need to retrieve on the main thread an identifier, ideally the property designated as `primaryKey`, and pass that over to the background thread.

You get a failure like that whenever you violate against that.

See our [the relevant chapter of our docs about "Passing Instances Across Threads"](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads):

> Unmanaged instances of RLMObjects behave exactly as regular NSObject subclasses, and are safe to pass across threads.
>
> Instances of RLMRealm, RLMResults, or RLMArray, or managed instances of RLMObject can only be used on the thread on which they were created, otherwise an exception is thrown*. This is one way Realm enforces transaction version isolation. Otherwise, it would be impossible to determine what should be done when an object is passed between threads at different transaction versions without a potentially extensive relationship graph.
>
> Instead, there are several ways to represent instances in ways that can be safely passed between threads. For example, an object with a primary key can be represented by its primary key’s value; or an RLMResults can be represented by its NSPredicate or query string; or an RLMRealm can be represented by its RLMRealmConfiguration. The target thread can then re-fetch the RLMRealm, RLMObject, RLMResults, or RLMArray using its thread-safe representation. Keep in mind that re-fetching will retrieve an instance at the version of the target thread, which may differ from the originating thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not 100% clear for me what we are doing wrong. We are calling 'objectsWithPredicate' or 'allObjects' when this problem occurs. We aren't passing the resulting objects to another thread, because the crash occurs before the results are returned. Or are we interpreting the stacktrace wrong?